# Сделать вывод find постраничным

Tags: linux

Здравствуйте.

Возможно ли сделать вывод **find** постраничным, чтобы файлы убегающие наверх можно было посмотреть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find . -type f | less

Comment: Вообще more - постраничный вывод, но less несоизмеримо удобнее

Comment: И ТС кстати не просил только регулярные файлы.

Comment: @pytak @ArcherGodsonну давайте) поумничайте)more - в одну сторону, less - в обефайлы потому что написав find | less - получил ругательство потому как ответ не может  быть короче 20 символов

Comment: Какие 20 символов, какой ответ, ты чего?))) даже на пустой файл less отрабатывает так как положено. )))

Comment: ))))  Антон имел ввиду ограничения хэшкода на размер поста.. я б вставил пробелов, но это моё мнение )

Answer (score 2):

Вот смотри ка, работает, если дать комментарий сначала

```
find | more
```

Comment: Я привык быть лаконичным, а не лить "воду" )давай еще цветом раскрась))

Comment: А ЧТО, МОЖНО?!!? )))))

Answer (score 2):

Чуваки а можно, я ?

```
find | vim -
```

Comment: Мож кому пригодится: [как выйти из vim][1] )))  [1]: http://wiki.firstvds.ru/index.php/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_vim_-_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE#.D0.9A.D0.B0.D0.BA_.D0.B2.D1.8B.D0.B9.D1.82.D0.B8_.D0.B8.D0.B7_.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B4.D0.B0.D0.BA.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B0_vi

Comment: Более удобная фича Shift ZQ, а с сохранением ваще красота Shift ZZ

Comment: круууть )) только это меня не заставит этим пользоваться )